# Bind a value to a javascript method as parameter

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, repeater

I'm getting error on binding a javascript method call using Eval().
Following is the line of code within a repeater control:

```
<asp:Button ID="View" runat="server" Text="View" CommandName="View" OnClientClick="OpenInNewWindow(<%# Eval("JobID")%>)">
                        </asp:Button>
```

I need to get the value jobId for that javascript method. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: `OnClientClick` is translated to `onClick` by ASP?

Comment: Yes OnClientClick is where we write the javascript method calls for the asp controls.

Comment: What is the possible content of JobID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<asp:Button ID="AddCartButton" runat="server" Text="Add To Cart" onClick="AddCartButton_Click" 
     OnClientClick='<%# Eval("JobID", "OpenInNewWindow(\"{0}\").ToString()") %>'/>
```

each single quote disorientate markup parser. Except this one, expression evaluated practically the same way as regular C# expression

Corrected the syntax

Comment: Some small issue is there in this code. Showing Compiler Error Message: CS1010: Newline in constant.

Comment: Got it. I corrected '<%# Eval("JobID", "OpenInNewWindow(\"{0}\").ToString()") %>'. And thanx a lot... It worked :)

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are missing quotes around JobID.

Try:

```
<asp:Button ID="View" runat="server" Text="View" CommandName="View" OnClientClick="OpenInNewWindow('<%# Eval("JobID")%>')">
</asp:Button>
```

Comment: Showing this error :
Parser Error Message: The server tag is not well formed.

Answer (score 0):

Either set the `OnClientClick` property in code behind or in code behind add the line `page.DataBind()`.  When the page is bound it will evaluate `JobID` and add the value to the page sent to the client.

If you need more info you could check [ASP.NET data binding overview](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307860) or [this](http://bytes.com/topic/asp-net/answers/299439-what-page-databind-doing-what-useful) post on another forum.
I usually avoid page binding, instead setting the properties in code behind.  While page binding is very useful, I have found it to be less predictable (did they call bind on page load?  In a button event?) and sometimes complicated (one variable needs to be bound on page load, but the other after).

Answer (score 0):

```
<asp:Button ID="View" runat="server" Text="View" CommandName="View" OnClientClick="window.open('yourpage.aspx?JobID=<# Eval("JobID")','','width=200,height=100')">
</asp:Button>
```

Comment: Showing this error : Parser Error Message: The server tag is not well formed.

Answer (score 0):

Don't bind the javascript function declaratively. Do it in code behind by capturing the itemdatabound event of the corresponding grid. In this event first get the reference to the button then define bind the javascript function as:

```
    int JobID = DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "JobID").ToString();
    Btn.Attributes.Add("OnClientClick","javascript:OpenInNewWindow(" + JobID + ")");
```

Hope that helps...